# symmetric group acting on torus

Tags: permutations, representation-theory, lie-groups, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Let $S_k$ be symmetric group of order $k$. Let $T^k=S^1\times\cdots \times S^1$. Then $T^k$ is a Lie group. For each $\sigma\in S_k$, let $\sigma$ act on $T^k$ from right in the way
$$
(s_1,\cdots,s_k)\sigma=(s_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,s_{\sigma(k)}).
$$
Can  $S_k$ be regarded as a subgroup of $T^k$ or not?

Comment: While I am not the downvoter, I am still curious: how can an automorphism be viewed as an element of the group?

Comment: for example, when the group is $\mathbb{Z}$, $Aut(\mathbb{Z})=\pm 1$.

Comment: In this case an automorphism can be viewed as an element of the group.

Comment: I can tell there are symbols common between the underlying sets, sure, but is multiplication-by-negative-one an element of the integers? Is a function an integer? What would it mean for an element of $S_k$ to be an element of $T^k$? Could I simply slap arbitrary labels on the underlying sets in such a way that I can arbitrarily declare $S_k$ a subset of $T^k$, or must it be meaningful in some way that pays attention to the fact that there is a right action going on? If so, how?

Comment: Ehh. Agree with whacka. Feels like an apples vs oranges thing to me, too. Also, the group of automorphisms of the **additive** group of $\Bbb{Z}$ is isomorphic (but not equal to) the **multiplicative** group $\{\pm1\}$. And the latter is **not** a subgroup of the additive group, because the latter has no non-trivial torsion elements.

Comment: And... the Torus is an abelian group, but the symmetric group is non-abelian, so we cannot even find an isomorphic copy of the latter inside the former.

Comment: We do have a subgroup of $n\times n$ matrices that is isomorphic to the semi-direct product $T^k\rtimes S_n$. That group consists of monomial matrices with the non-zero entries (one per row/column) coming from $S^1$. This is an idea that generalizes. If $H$ is a group of automorphisms of another group $K$, we can naturally give the Cartesian product $K\times H$ a group structure such that conjugation by an element of $H$ on $K$ amounts to applying the associated automorphism. This is the semi-direct product $K\rtimes H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to conflate automorphisms of an abelian group with elements of the abelian group. Since many notations are ubiquitous in math, such as $\pm1$, you may incidentally find a single symbol used for both an element of a group and an automorphism of a group. This is not the same as saying the automorphism is being viewed as an element of the group, anymore than arbitrarily declaring you will refer to the number two as "apple" and also use the word "apple" to refer to the identity permutation means that the number two is being thought of as the identity map.

We certainly can't view $S_k$ as a subgroup of $\Bbb T^k$; the first is nonabelian, the second isn't.

You can however put $\Bbb T^k$ and $S_k$ in the same group in which conjugating a toral vector by a permutation achieves the effect of having the permutation permute the coordinates of the toral vector. This construction is known as the [wreath product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product) $\Bbb T\wr S_k$. As Jyrki mentions in the comments, it is a special case of a semidirect product $K\rtimes H$, in which conjugating elements of $K$ by elements of $H$ achieves the effect of having $H$ act on $K$ by automorphisms.